# transition a dynamic height div from top to vertical center

Tags: css, css-transitions, vertical-alignment

I want to transition a dynamic height div from the top of the parent to the center.

There are various ways to vertically align a div with dynamic height to the center of its parent such as with CSS tables + `vertical-align:middle` or flexbox - however the problem is that `vertical-align:middle` and the flexbox `align-items` properties are not [animatable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Take a look:

### CSS tables + `vertical-align:middle`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Zg2/16/)**

```css
.block {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.centered {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: pink;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.block:hover .centered {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <div class="centered">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
  </div>

</div>
```

and

### flexbox

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Zg2/17/)**

```css
 .block {
   background: orange;
   height: 150px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s;
   -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -o-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
 }
 .centered {
   text-align: center;
   background: pink;
   top: 0;
 }
 .block:hover {
   align-items: center;
   /* align vertical */
 }
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <div class="centered">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut 
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there a method that of vertical centering that supports transition from top to center?

Answer (score 4):

The `transform: translateY(-50%);` method works well here.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3wL5jeex/2/)**

```css
.block {
   background: orange;
   height: 150px;
 }
 .centered {
   text-align: center;
   background: pink;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s;
   -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -o-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
 }
 .block:hover .centered {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="centered">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna</div>
</div>
```